# Ubuntu Server Apache2 SSL virtual host not working

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

I have fully set up a web server on ubuntu using SSL encryption. I am trying to set up the default -SSL file to point to the correct directories. geekychicgirls works completely fine, however thepeepinghole always resolves to geekychicgirls, any help is appreciated see code below.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@nixcraft.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/thepeepinghole"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl/14252798.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl/futureretrogaming.ca-bundle
    ServerName www.thepeepinghole.tk
    ServerAlias thepeepinghole.tk
    ErrorLog "/var/www/thepeepinghole/log/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/thepeepinghole/log/access.log" common
    <Directory /var/www/thepeepinghole>
                DirectoryIndex index.html
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@nixcraft.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/geekychicgirls"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl/14252798.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl/futureretrogaming.ca-bundle
    ServerName www.geekychicgirls.tk
    ServerAlias geekychicgirls.tk
    ErrorLog "/var/www/geekychicgirls/log/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/geekychicgirls/log/access.log" common
    <Directory /var/www/geekychicgirls>
                DirectoryIndex index.html
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to first make sure the `apache2.conf` includes the `sites-enabled` folder and not the `sites-available` folder.

Then, you need to create an additional symbolic link in your `sites-enabled` folder that links to the `ssl` default file you created in the `sites-available` folder. Finally restart the apache2 service and you should be good to go.

Comment: Tip: You don't need to manually create the symbolic link. You can use `sudo a2ensite <your_site_file_name_in_sites-available>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

> NameVirtualHost *:443

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@nixcraft.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/thepeepinghole"
    SSLEngine on
...
```

Edit 1

Only I can say is: now try something completely different.

Edit /etc/apache2/ports.conf and add the following line:

```
Listen 443
```

Also comment out the following in /etc/apache2/ports.conf:

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # SSL name based virtual hosts are not yet supported, therefore no
    # NameVirtualHost statement here
   Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Create a file called /etc/apache2/ssl.conf and put in all from your posted file in question without on beginning  and  at the end.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@nixcraft.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/thepeepinghole"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl/14252798.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl/futureretrogaming.ca-bundle
    ServerName www.thepeepinghole.tk
    ServerAlias thepeepinghole.tk
    ErrorLog "/var/www/thepeepinghole/log/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/thepeepinghole/log/access.log" common
    <Directory /var/www/thepeepinghole>
                DirectoryIndex index.html
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@nixcraft.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/geekychicgirls"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl/14252798.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl/futureretrogaming.ca-bundle
    ServerName www.geekychicgirls.tk
    ServerAlias geekychicgirls.tk
    ErrorLog "/var/www/geekychicgirls/log/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/geekychicgirls/log/access.log" common
    <Directory /var/www/geekychicgirls>
                DirectoryIndex index.html
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Add in an include line in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
Include "/etc/apache2/ssl.conf"
```

Restart Apache2 with: apache2ctl restart

Comment: Hi, I have tried what you mentioned and it did not fix it.

Comment: try sudo a2ensite thepeepinghole.tk

Comment: I got this error in return: ERROR: Site thepeepinghole.tk does not exist!

Comment: Maybe is catch in folder name for site. Try sudo a2ensite thepeepinghole Widthout .tk

Comment: Somehow I"m still getting, ERROR: Site thepeepinghole does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a script that you can use in order to generate and automatically install Self-Signed Certificates for Virtual Hosts configuration files already created. You can find the script by consulting this tutorial http://www.bytelinux.com/create-self-signed-certificates-enable-apache-ssl-ubuntu-14-10/ and create the a2sslcert bash script on your own server.